# How to jump to the code from the VS 2015 Output window line where a Debug.WriteLine was executed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am wondering is it possible to jump to the code line from the VS 2015 Output window line where a Debug.WriteLine was executed say with double click? I suppose VS 2015 not supporting this feature out of the box (missed I something?) but I am hoping there an extension or similar.

Please note: It is not as extreme as it sounds, Unity IDE supports this for ages, also in Chrome dev tools you can click on an output line in the Console that jumps to the source where it was executed.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to provide that location information in the output text.
For example, you can format your output like that:

```
CString s;
s.Format(L"%S(%d): %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, L"Test output");
OutputDebugString(s);
```